# How to ADD an environment variable that can be used by other process in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

In a graphical DE, like KDE, what command can be used to add a new environment variable that can be used by any other process?

Note:

1) I'm aware of `export A=B`, but it only works for subsequent processes started in the same shell that executed the `export`, processes started else where, like a graphical application such as Chrome, won't be aware of the export.

2) I'm also aware that you can put it into `~/.bash_profile` or alike, but that would need a restart/relogin for the setting to take effect.

Is there something like `export` but have effect for all applications and doesn't require a significant restart?

Comment: You could save a value to a file maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that you need to restart after placing a variable definition (whether through an `export` statement or otherwise) in `~/.bash_profile`, is flawed. You only need to `source` the file again after making modifications:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or the more portable version:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Either statement will (re)load any definitions in that file into your current shell. Sourcing is not the same as executing the script: it will modify the environment in the calling shell itself, not a subshell running the script.

A file like `~/.bash_profile` may have many other definitions and settings in it that will mess with the shell. It is better to create a small (temporary) snippet with just the variables you want, and source that instead, as @JeremiahMegel suggests.

If you want to change the environment for a single process you run from the command line, you can set the variables on the same command line:

```
VAR=value /usr/bin/gedit
```

This will run `gedit` with the environment variable `VAR` set to `value`, but only for that one child process.

Unfortunately, your desktop applications are a bit more static than that. Most of the graphical applications you see in the menus are probably going to be represented by `.desktop` files in a folder like `/usr/share/applications`. These files are run in an environment that has almost none of the variables you are expecting. They rely on absolute paths, and most of the configuration is done by pointing the `.desktop` file to a script that performs its own setup. You can modify some of these files on an individual basis if you absolutely have to, but I would not recommend doing that. If you do insist on messing around with the graphical apps on your desktop, I would recommend making a copy of the desktop files you plan to modify in to `~/.local/share/applications`, or whatever the equivalent is on your system. Those files will override anything found in `/usr/share/applications` and will only affect you.